# How to check if a string contains any string of a column in MySQL and vice versa?

Tags: mysql, string-comparison

By vice versa, I mean, check if any of the strings in a column contains the string.

Example:

String a = "Peperoni"

MySQL column:

```
{
    "PPeperoni_123",
    "roni",
    "hello world"
}
```

It should return the first 2 rows.

(Note: im looking for the query string for this)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but are you maybe looking for this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE column LIKE "%string%" OR string LIKE CONCAT("%", column, "%")
```

Comment: LIKE CONCAT("%", column, "%") is not secure if the value of the column contains %

Answer (score 0):

with Mysql you can use [`SOUNDS LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like) to find the nearest matches

[**example**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-sounds_like-function.php)

`SELECT *  FROM table WHERE column SOUNDS LIKE 'Peperoni' ;`

Comment: Thank you, that also helps me on a similar issue.

Comment: Sounds like can not return that result it compares string phonetically