# What is the condition to check if a string contains any string of a column and vice versa?

Tags: mysql, sql

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862257/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-any-string-of-a-column-in-mysql-and-vice-versa) and tested the answers but noticed that executing `SELECT ... WHERE column LIKE "%string%" OR string LIKE CONCAT("%", column, "%")`

string `LIKE CONCAT("%", column, "%")` is not secure if the value of the column contains `%` and secondly if the column is null it returning true which is not correct since the column contains nothing.

Comment: It seems that you are looking MySQL ESCAPE CHARACTERS using LIKE.. here's the link and look for escape character: http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/like.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just escape the percent signs, if any exist:

```
SELECT column1
FROM table
WHERE (
    column2 LIKE "%string%"
    OR string LIKE CONCAT("%", REPLACE(column2, '%', '|%'), "%") ESCAPE |
    )
    AND column2 IS NOT NULL;
```

The default escape character is a backslash but this is not ANSI compliant and can be a pain to work with if you're building a query in another language. So I use the [`LIKE ... ESCAPE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) to specify my own escape.

`CONCAT()` returns `NULL` [if any of its arguments are null](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), so if you're concerned about that, just [check for it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null).

Comment: `CONCAT()` returns `NULL` [if any of its arguments are null][2], so if you're concerned about that, just [check for it][3]. I know that but ignore yet it is very important!!!